# Union of two open, open-unicoherent sets whose intersection is connected

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

I stumbled upon the following proposition, and haven't found an error in my proof yet.

By "open-unicoherence" I mean unicoherence with closed sets replaced with open sets in the definition.

> Let $X$ be a locally connected space. If $U$ and $V$ are open, open-unicoherent subsets of $X$ such that $X = U \cup V$ and $U \cap V$ is connected, then $X$ is open-unicoherent.

This is similar to the van Kampen theorem but its statement is purely point-set. I wonder if this (or its negation) is a known result, and in case it isn't, if this is something someone has interest in. I'm aware of the result of Pierce (the paper 'Special Unions of Unicoherent Continua') that if $X$ is a Hausdorff continuum, $A$ and $B$ are closed unicoherent subsets of $X$ such that $X = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ is connected and locally connected, then $X$ is unicoherent. Actually, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103599/van-kampen-like-property-for-unicoherence) question about 5 years ago. Unless I'm mistaken, the proof of the above proposition is pretty simple and fits in a few pages.

Comment: What does open unicoherent mean? (I know what unicoherent means)

Comment: It is unicoherence but closed sets are replaced with open sets. So, a space is open unicoherent if whenever it is represented as the union of two open connected sets, the intersection of those two open sets is connected. Probably this is not a standard definition, and I thought it is maybe because I saw it somewhere. My apologies.